# How to add file attachments to .NET SmtpClient MailMessage email from a form submission

Tags: c#, attachment, smtpclient

I have an MVC form which has 3 file input fields on it. If those input fields have values on them, I want to add them as an attachment to a notification email. Please note that in the example below `addedFiles` is a `HttpFileCollectionBase`.

```
        var smtpServer = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("MailServer");
        var smtpPort = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("MailServerPort");
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var mailClient = new SmtpClient(smtpServer, Convert.ToInt16(smtpPort)))
        using (var emailMessage = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, message))
        {
            if (addedFiles != null && addedFiles.Count > 0)
            {
                //for some reason, the first file field was getting repeated at the end.  Workaround.
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    string fileName = addedFiles.Keys[i];
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = addedFiles[fileName];
                    if ((file.FileName.Contains(".pdf") ||
                        file.FileName.Contains(".doc")) && file.ContentLength > 0 && file.ContentLength < 10485760)
                    {

                        var fStream = file.InputStream;
                        fStream.Position = 0;
                        fStream.CopyTo(stream);
                        var s = stream.ToArray();
                        stream.Write(s, 0, file.ContentLength);
                        stream.Position = 0; 

                        emailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, file.FileName));


                    }
                }
                    await Task.Run(() => mailClient.Send(emailMessage));                  
            }
        }
```

What is currently happening is the email is generated and the files do get attached. The size of the file is correct in the email attachment (if not a few KB larger than the original). However, upon attempting to open the file, I get a message that it is corrupted. The test file is a .docx file. I have tested the original file to ensure it is not corrupted and I am able to open it so I do know it's not the file. I'm sure I'm missing something silly. Just need a little guidance.

**UPDATE**

The issue is only with docx files.  Pdf and doc files are fine.  I'm not sure why only docx file come through as corrupted.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the Streams incorrectly. You need to use a separate `Stream` for each `Attachment`.

As a neat trick, (I believe) you don't need an intermediate stream or buffer - but you can pass the file-upload streams directly to the `Attachment` constructors **provided the `MailMessage` will be sent before the ASP.NET Request/Response lifecycle ends**. (Note that `Attachment` takes ownership of the stream passed into its constructor, so you don't need to dispose of the attachment's stream yourself *provided that the parent `MailMessage` is also disposed*).

Also there's a few things that don't look right in your code (such as hardcoding `3` for the number of files) and doing `await Task.Run( ... )` for a non-async operation.

As you're using the `System.Web` version of ASP.NET (i.e. *not* using ASP.NET Core) I don't recommend using any `async` APIs because that messes with the request/response lifecycle.

Try this:

```
HttpFileCollectionBase addedFiles = ...
using( SmtpClient  mailClient = new SmtpClient( smtpServer, Convert.ToInt16( smtpPort ) ) )
using( MailMessage emailMessage = new MailMessage( fromAddress, toAddress, subject, message ) )
{
    if( addedFiles?.Count > 0 )
    {
        foreach( HttpPostedFileBase file in addedFiles )
        {
            Boolean isOK = ( file.FileName.EndsWith( ".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) || file.FileName.EndsWith( ".doc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) && file.ContentLength > 0 && file.ContentLength < 10485760;
            if( isOK )
            {
                Attachment att = new Attachment( file.InputStream, name: file.FileName );
                emailMessage.Attachments.Add( att );
            } 
        }
    }

    mailClient.Send( emailMessage );
}
```

If you do need to have the `MailMessage` outlast the ASP.NET request/response lifecycle, or if you want to inspect or process the uploaded files before attaching them, then you'll need to buffer them individually, like so:

```
HttpFileCollectionBase addedFiles = ...
using( SmtpClient  mailClient = new SmtpClient( smtpServer, Convert.ToInt16( smtpPort ) ) )
using( MailMessage emailMessage = new MailMessage( fromAddress, toAddress, subject, message ) )
{
    if( addedFiles?.Count > 0 )
    {
        foreach( HttpPostedFileBase file in addedFiles )
        {
            Boolean isOK = ( file.FileName.EndsWith( ".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) || file.FileName.EndsWith( ".doc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) && file.ContentLength > 0 && file.ContentLength < 10485760;
            if( isOK )
            {
                MemoryStream copy = new MemoryStream( capacity: file.ContentLength );
                file.InputStream.CopyTo( copy );
                // Rewind the stream, this is important! (You cannot rewind ASP.NET's file.InputStream, hence why we use a MemoryStream copy).
                copy.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );

                DoSomethingWithFileStream( copy );

                // Rewind the stream again, this is important!
                copy.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );

                Attachment att = new Attachment( copy, name: file.FileName );
                emailMessage.Attachments.Add( att );
            } 
        }
    }

    mailClient.Send( emailMessage );
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will update my code.  I've literally spent all day working on something that should have been simple. I kept using a docx file as my test.  It's the docx file type that is the issue.  Pdf, and doc are correct. Any idea why ONLY a docx file would be corrupted?.  As an aside, I am using async and I'm actually sending 3 emails to 3 different email addresses.  I was getting errors until I switched to that.

Comment: @Mikeyp I understand the PDF and (non-OOXML) DOC file formats allow "junk" data at the end of their files, but the newer formats are less forgiving. I feel there's also some non-deterministic behaviour in how you were incorrectly using the `Stream` objects in your original code, so I wouldn't dwell too much on it.